# trying to run simply code in react but getting error

Tags: reactjs

I've built simple code in React that just takes values from HTML inputs and when the button click show results in span. but getting errors and wondering why
is anyone know how I can fix it?
............................................................................

**calc.js code**

```
     import React from 'react'

const spanResult = document.querySelector(".span-result");
const inputOne = document.querySelector(".input-one");
const inputTwo = document.querySelector(".input-two");
const btnResult = document.querySelector(".btn-result");



function add() {

    var inputOneValue = inputOne.value;
    console.log(inputOneValue)
    var inputTwoValue = inputTwo.value;
    console.log(inputTwoValue)
    var finalResult = Number(inputOneValue + inputTwoValue);
    console.log(finalResult)
    spanResult.innerHTML = finalResult;

}



export default function Calc() {

    return (

        <div>
            <h1>Simple calcultaor</h1>
            <label>enter number one:</label>
            <input className='input-one' type="number" defaultValue={0} /> <br />
            <label>enter second number:</label>
            <input type="number" className='input-two' defaultValue={0} /> <br />
            <button onClick={add} className='btn-result'> See result</button>
            <h2>The result is: <span className='span-result'>hello</span></h2>
            {console.log(spanResult)}


        </div>
    )
}

// when user click on button
// take two value from input and plus them
// show result in span innerText
```

**App.js code**

```
import React from 'react'
import Calc from './calc'

function App() {

  
  return <div>
    <Calc  />
 


  </div>
}


export default App;
```

[errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rgVCt.png)

Comment: May I know why you are are using querySelector?

Comment: You seen to mess React.js & vanilla Javascript, I recommend using React code correctly.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you give class name input-one to label not input so you get the null value instead and error.
use element event listener like onClick not {btnResult.addEventListener('click', add)}.

```
<button className='btn-result' onClick={add}> See result</button>
```

The best way is to learn how to work with states not query selectors.

check this
[how to sum two inputs with React hooks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65748685/how-to-sum-two-inputs-with-react-hooks)

Comment: I see the form now in the window but when i click the button and write two input i'm getting error and not getting the result display. " TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'value')
    at add (calc.js:12:1) " i update the code u can see

Comment: change defaultValue to value
but the right solutions is in the link that I've attached in the answer
you need to work with states not query selectors